# SELECT data from two table get NULL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to write SELECT statement (JOIN) of two table. 
First one is KPOL table second one is SIFRAD and I  want display all employee which release policy in 2013.
When I type query like this notthing happened

```
SELECT P.SIFRA_RAD, S.IME, P.DAT_IZD
FROM AUTO.SIFRAD S, AUTO.KPOL P
WHERE S.IME = P.SIFRA_RAD AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM P.DAT_IZD)= '2013'
```

But when I select DAT_IZD I get the bunch of data

```
SELECT DAT_IZD
FROM AUTO.KPOL
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DAT_IZD)='2013' ORDER BY DAT_IZD ASC
```

I have no idea where I make mistake. Query look like alright but It doesnt return anything. 
Any suggestion and comment where I made mistake ?

**UPDATE**

I want to display which Employee release policy in 2013 year. 
The first table is KPOL which contain DAT_IZD (date of release)
Second one is AUTO.SIFRAD which is Employee table which contain SIFRA_R and IME
And SIFRA_R is key in table AUTO.KPOL which contain SIFRA_RAD
in picure belove you can see all details

```
"SIFRA_RAD"  "IME"      "DAT_IZD"

"00456"     "Test"      "1.3.2013"
"00465      "Test123"   "1.3.2013"
"00469"     "Test111"   "1.3.2013"
```

Comment: can you please provide sample data? It is probably because of the incompatible data types while comparing `S.IME = P.SIFRA_RAD`

Comment: @ Derviş Kayımbaşıoğlu  I updated my question, you can check picture above for data and example :)

Comment: Please show sample data for both tables in tabular form, not as images.

Comment: Unfortunately the data which is here contain private information of user and can not be display over here.
Address,Name,Surname,PhoneNumber,CreditCardNo :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty first result set indicates that there is no record in the `AUTO.SIFRAD` table which matches to any record in the `AUTO.KPOL` table which also has a `DAT_IZD` date in 2013.  You could mitigate this problem by rephrasing your query as a left join, and by moving the `WHERE` logic to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT P.SIFRA_RAD, S.IME, P.DAT_IZD
FROM AUTO.SIFRAD S
LEFT JOIN AUTO.KPOL P
    ON S.IME = P.SIFRA_RAD AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM P.DAT_IZD) = 2013;
```

This should still show no data for the `DAT_IZD` column, but it would at least return all records from the `AUTO.SIFRAD` table.

Comment: No, the query is working, but your _logic_ doesn't work.  Add sample data to your question to show us what you want to happen here.

Comment: I updated my question. I hope now is clear what I want to do 
Display which employee release policy in 2013 JOIN table AUTO.KPOL and AUTO.SIFRAD
AUTO.KPOL contain SIFRA_RAD(EmployeeID) and DAT_IZD (Date of release) and  AUTO.SIFRAD contain SIFRA_R(EmployeeID) and IME(Name)